# Understanding Terry Tao's proof of the Brauer-Fowler theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

I'm trying to understand how Terry Tao got to the last inequality in [this blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/quasirandom-groups-and-a-cheap-version-of-the-brauer-fowler-theorem/#more-6654). Here is my attempt If we exclude the trivial character, then we have 
$$
|G|-1 = \sum_{\chi\in\hat{G}\backslash 1}{\chi(1)^2}
$$
Then using Cauchy-Schwarz and a previous result
$$
\sum_{\chi\in\hat{G}\backslash 1}{\chi(1)^2} \geq \frac{1}{|\hat{G}|-1}\left(\sum_{\chi\in\hat{G}\backslash 1}{\chi(1)}\right)^2 \geq \frac{1}{|\hat{G}|-1}\left(\frac{|G|}{n}\right)^2
$$
Thus,
$$
|\hat{G}|-1 \geq \frac{1}{|G|-1}\left(\frac{|G|}{n}\right)^2
$$
But the inequality I want is
$$
\frac{|G|-1}{n^2}\leq |\hat{G}|-1
$$
How can I arrive at this result?

Comment: $|G|^2\ge |G|^2-2|G|+1$?

Comment: You just need to show that  $|G|^{2}/(|G|-1) \geq |G|-1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
|\hat{G}|-1 \geq \frac{1}{|G|-1}\left(\frac{|G|}{n}\right)^2\implies\frac{|G|^2}{n^2\left(|G|-1\right)}\le|\hat G|-1$$

But

$$\frac{|G|^2}{n^2\left(|G|-1\right)}\ge\frac{|G|-1}{n^2}\iff|G|^2\ge(|G|-1)^2$$